# haproxy reload from stats socket?

Tags: haproxy

I know that I can reload haproxy from a shell command (I use `service haproxy reload`).

I also am using the stats socket to enable and disable servers when doing maintenance on them.  I also have worked with the stats webserver, although it's disabled at the moment.

Is it possible to use the stats socket to force a reload, too? (The use case is to let a person without admin privs on the server add a new https certificate to the network folder where I am storing them, and use reload to make sure haproxy sees it.)

My config, sanitized:

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats socket ipv4@172.16.63.123:9999 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        # ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE+aRSA+AES256+GCM+SHA384:ECDHE+aRSA+AES128+GCM+SHA256:ECDHE+aRSA+AES256+SHA384:ECDHE+aRSA+AES128+SHA256:ECDHE+aRSA+RC4+SHA:ECDHE+aRSA+AES256+SHA:ECDHE+aRSA+AES128+SHA:AES256+GCM+SHA384:AES128+GCM+SHA256:AES128+SHA256:AES256+SHA256:DHE+aRSA+AES128+SHA:RC4+SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 50000
        timeout client  500000
        timeout server  500000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-in
        acl host_onedomain hdr(host) -i -m end onedomain.com
        ;;; additional, similar domain acls omitted
        acl ip_172_16_55_96 dst 172.16.55.96

        http-request set-header HTTPS ON if { ssl_fc }

        bind *:80
        bind *:443 ssl crt /media/windowsshare/winserver/ssl/pem/
        use_backend staging if host_staging
        use_backend production if host_production
        default_backend staging

backend staging
        server SERVER1 172.16.55.91:82 maxconn 64
        server SERVER2 172.16.55.92:82 maxconn 64

backend production
        server SERVER1 172.16.55.91:81 maxconn 64
        server SERVER2 172.16.55.92:80 maxconn 64


listen stats *:1936
        stats enable
        stats uri /
        stats hide-version
        stats auth sysadmin:password
        stats admin if TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, no.

You can't reload the whole process from the socket, and all details about using the admin sockets are listed under section *9.2 Unix Socket commands* of the [management docs](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/doc/management.txt).

Comment: This makes sense, considering that "reloading" HAProxy actually starts a new haproxy process which then tells the old process to hand over control of the listening sockets and shut itself down once its existing sessions finish.

Comment: My final solution was to add a crontab entry that checks the folder's last modified date against `/run/haproxy.pid`. If the folder is newer, it reloads haproxy. This achieves the effect that I needed.